# Questions about uniform buffer objects

Tags: opengl, shader, opengl-4

Is it guaranteed that if a uniform block is declared the same in multiple shader programs, say

```
uniform Matrices
{
    mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
    mat4 CameraMatrix;
    mat4 ModelMatrix;
};
```

Will it have the same block index returned by `glGetUniformBlockIndex(program, "Matrices")`?

If the answer is yes, then I'm able to query the index of the block once and use it for all the shader programs that contain that block, right?

Second question: will `ProjectionMatrix`, `CameraMatrix`, `ModelMatrix`, always have the same layout order in memory, respectively? I'm asking this because the tutorial I read uses the next functions

```
// Query for the offsets of each block variable
const GLchar *names[] = { "InnerColor", "OuterColor",
"RadiusInner", "RadiusOuter" };
GLuint indices[4];
glGetUniformIndices(programHandle, 4, names, indices);
GLint offset[4];
glGetActiveUniformsiv(programHandle, 4, indices,
GL_UNIFORM_OFFSET, offset);
```

And I'm not sure if that's really needed, as long as I know the uniforms order inside the uniform block..?

Comment: Can you link the tutorial you're following here?

Comment: It's actually a book. OpenGL 4.0 Shading Language Cookbook

Comment: Nice, I've the first edition of the book, the author does a good job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will `ProjectionMatrix`, `CameraMatrix`, `ModelMatrix`, always have the same layout order in memory, respectively?

No. Here's what the standard states (emphasis mine):

> If *pname* is `UNIFORM_BLOCK_DATA_SIZE`, then the implementation-
>   dependent minimum total buffer object size, in basic machine units, required to hold all active uniforms in the uniform block identified by *uniformBlockIndex* is returned. **It is neither guaranteed nor expected that a given implementation will arrange uniform values as tightly packed in a buffer object.** The exception to this is the `std140` uniform block layout, which guarantees specific packing behavior and does not require the application to query for offsets and strides.
>
> I'm not sure if that's really needed, as long as I know the uniforms order inside the uniform block..?

So, yes, the author is right in *not* assuming the layout is contiguous and does what's sensible (guaranteed to work always in all implementations): gets the uniform indices and assigns their values respectively.

> Specifying layout(std140) will do the trick then, right?

Yes, you can avoid querying the location and uploading data every time by making use of both uniform buffer objects and `std140`. However, make sure you understand its alignment requirements. This information is detailed in [`ARB_uniform_buffer_object`'s specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/uniform_buffer_object.txt). For an elaborate treatment with examples see OpenTK's article on [Uniform Buffer Objects (UBO) using the std140 layout specification](http://www.opentk.com/node/2926).

> Is it guaranteed that if a uniform block is declared the same in multiple shader programs, will it have the same block index returned by `glGetUniformBlockIndex(program, "Matrices")`?

No. I've searched the OpenGL 3.3 specification which gives no such guarantees. From the standard's viewpoint, uniform blocks (default or named) are associated to a program, period. No existence/association of uniform blocks beyond a program is made in the specification.

> Because there is no guarantee that uniform blocks will have the same index in different shader program, that means I need to call `glBindBufferBase()` everytime I switch programs, right?

Yes, see `ARB_uniform_buffer_object`'s specification for an example.

Comment: Specifying layout(std140) will do the trick then, right? (at least for three mat4's like the example above). One more question: Because there is no guarantee that uniform blocks will have the same index in different shader program, that means I need to call `glBindBufferBase()` everytime I switch programs, right?

Comment: About my first question:
I know that uniform blocks are designed for sharing uniforms in multiple programs, but they never say that the same uniform block will be assigned the same index in different programs. (by the way, did you change your answer? Yesterday you said the opposite!)

Comment: You definitely answered my questions, however, it seems like a certain uniform block always has the same index when using different shader programs. I opened a new question for this. Thanks! [link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693916/uniform-block-index-in-different-shaders)

Comment: Sure, the whole point of having a function `glGetUniformBlockIndex(program, name)` shows that the UBO's index would change between programs. Thanks for the link.

Comment: The way I do it is when I create the Uniform Buffer Object I set it a binding index, then I never have to check its index again, because in each shader I have layout (binding = 2, std140) uniform perObjBuffer {// Your data here//}
Surely this works and it never changes index.

Comment: Yeah, I think the `layout(binding = 2, std140)` makes sure the binding index is always 2. Good point.