# Uniform block index in different shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl

Looking at [uniform_buffer_object](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/uniform_buffer_object.txt) specs, there is no guarantee that a certain uniform block that is defined the same way in multiple shader programs will have the same index returned by `glGetUniformBlockIndex()`. That means I have to call `glBindBufferBase()` to assign the UBO the relevant index every time I switch the shader program.

However, from some testing, it seems like a uniform block *does* have the same index in different shader programs, even when the uniform blocks are declared in different orders.
Have a look at these two vertex shaders: [one](http://pastebin.com/V1XMwdg2), [two](http://pastebin.com/6ZKnEL74). (note I used the values of `v1`, `v2`.. etc to avoid inactive uniform elimination)

When querying the indices like this:

```
std::cout << glGetUniformBlockIndex(prog1, "var1") << "\n";
std::cout << glGetUniformBlockIndex(prog2, "var1") << "\n";
```

I get the same index value. I get the same results when querying `"var2"`, `"var3"` and so on.

Is this intended? Why does it happen? Can I rely on this always happening?

Answer (score 3):

After you get the index you should set the binding point:

```
glUniformBlockBinding(prog1, glGetUniformBlockIndex(prog1, "var1"), 1);
glUniformBlockBinding(prog2, glGetUniformBlockIndex(prog2, "var1"), 1);
```

Now 1 is the binding point of `var1` in each program.

You can also set the binding in glsl explicitly:

```
layout(binding = 3) uniform MatrixBlock
{
  mat4 projection;
  mat4 modelview;
};
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know this. However this is core only in opengl 4.2 and later versions.

Comment: @pilpel I was just going to lookup the supported version, thanks!

Comment: note that on my config under linux (r600-hd3400) with latest mesa, layout(index = 1) is working and it's not possible to get UniformBlockIndex on CPU side.

Comment: @j-p Then your card must support OpenGL 4.2+ or has [`GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shading_language_420pack.txt). Read [Layout Qualifier](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29) for details.

Comment: @legends: no, only 3.3, but some extra function of later GL seems to be  availaible,